# R - apply function on two files in folders with for loop or lapply and save results in one dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, subset, lapply

I have a data set in "data" with 20 folders, which are identical in their structure. The only difference at the level of the folders are their names (from "1" to "20"). Please see the pattern below. The files have always the same file name and the same column structure. There might be a difference in the column length in the `.csv` files between folders, but not between the `.csv` files in the same folder. There are no missing values in the data frames. I want to work with the columns "mean" from the files.

### Data structure

```
data
- 1 (folder)
  - alpha (file)
    - mean (column)
    - .... (more columns)
  - beta (file)
    - mean (column)
    - .... (more columns)
  - ... (more files)
 
- 2 (folder)
  - alpha (file)
    - mean (column)
    - .... (more columns)
  - beta (file)
    - mean (column)
    - .... (more columns)
  - ... (more files)

- ... (more folders with the same structure)
```

I would like to compare the mean from alpha to the mean from beta in one folder. In the end however, I would like to have one dataframe which is subsetted of all the results of all individual folders. So I can create faceted boxplots and descriptive statistics out of this dataframe.

I am still new to R and apparently lack the skills for it (also sorry for the complicated code and my English). I can manually perform the task for one folder each, but I can not put the findings together with a for loop or lapply solution.

I have found many threads where data frames need to be merged without prior executing of a function from two files in the same folder. I do hope I produced a workable minimal example with 2 data frames each from 2 folders.

```
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
```

```
alpha1 <- read_csv('data/1/alpha.csv')
beta1 <- read_csv('data/1/beta.csv')
alpha2 <- read_csv('data/2/alpha2.csv')
beta2 <- read_csv('data/2/beta2.csv')
```

### Folder 1

```
alpha1 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J", "K"), mean = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), mean = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))



beta1 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J", "K"), mean = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), mean = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

```
alpha_mean <- alpha1 %>% select(mean_alpha = mean)
alphabeta <- alpha_mean %>% add_column(mean_beta = beta1$mean) 
alphabeta_table <- ddply(alphabeta, .(), transform, alphabeta = (mean_alpha/mean_beta))
alphabeta_table

    .id mean_alpha mean_beta alphabeta
1  <NA>          1         2 0.5000000
2  <NA>          2         3 0.6666667
3  <NA>          3         4 0.7500000
4  <NA>          4         5 0.8000000
5  <NA>          5         6 0.8333333
6  <NA>          6         7 0.8571429
7  <NA>          7         8 0.8750000
8  <NA>          8         9 0.8888889
9  <NA>          9        10 0.9000000
10 <NA>         10        11 0.9090909
11 <NA>         11        12 0.9166667
```

### Folder 2

```
alpha2 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J", "K", "L", "M"), mean = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), mean = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))



beta2 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J", "K", "L", "M"), mean = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), mean = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

```
alpha2_mean <- alpha2 %>% select(mean_alpha = mean)
alphabeta2 <- alpha2_mean %>% add_column(mean_beta = beta2$mean) 
alphabeta2_table <- ddply(alphabeta2, .(), transform, alphabeta = (mean_alpha/ mean_beta))
alphabeta2_table


    .id mean_alpha mean_beta alphabeta
1  <NA>          2         3 0.6666667
2  <NA>          3         4 0.7500000
3  <NA>          4         5 0.8000000
4  <NA>          5         6 0.8333333
5  <NA>          6         7 0.8571429
6  <NA>          7         8 0.8750000
7  <NA>          8         9 0.8888889
8  <NA>          9        10 0.9000000
9  <NA>         10        11 0.9090909
10 <NA>         11        12 0.9166667
11 <NA>         12        13 0.9230769
12 <NA>         13        14 0.9285714
13 <NA>         14        15 0.9333333
```

### Desired output

My desired output would be:

```
   .id        mean_alpha mean_beta  alphabeta
1  1              1         2       0.5000000
2  1              2         3       0.6666667
3  1              3         4       0.7500000
4  1              4         5       0.8000000
5  1              5         6       0.8333333
6  1              6         7       0.8571429
7  1              7         8       0.8750000
8  1              8         9       0.8888889
9  1              9        10       0.9000000
10 1             10        11       0.9090909
11 1             11        12       0.9166667
1  2              2         3       0.6666667
2  2              3         4       0.7500000
3  2              4         5       0.8000000
4  2              5         6       0.8333333
5  2              6         7       0.8571429
6  2              7         8       0.8750000
7  2              8         9       0.8888889
8  2              9        10       0.9000000
9  2             10        11       0.9090909
10 2             11        12       0.9166667
11 2             12        13       0.9230769
12 2             13        14       0.9285714
13 2             14        15       0.9333333
1  3             ...       ...      ...
2  3             ...       ...      ...
...
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: for this type of problem I tend to use `purrr::map_df(set_names(list_of_files), read_csv, .id = "id")`. I would avoid using plyr with tidyverse - you rarely need plyr when working on data.frames. dplyr is easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution :

1. Get all the folders using `list.dirs`.
2. For each folder read the "alpha" and "beta" files and return a 3 column tibble back with `alpha`, `beta` and `alphabeta` values.
3. Bind all the dataframes with and `id` column to know from which folder each value is coming.

```
all_folders <- list.dirs('Data/', recursive = FALSE, full.names = TRUE)

result <- purrr::map_df(all_folders, function(x) {
  all_Files <- list.files(x, full.names = TRUE, pattern = 'alpha|beta')
  df1 <- read.csv(all_Files[1])
  df2 <- read.csv(all_Files[2])
  tibble::tibble(alpha = df1$mean, beta = df2$mean, alphabeta = alpha/beta)
}, .id = "id")
```

Comment: Your post helped tremendously. However, the original numerical sequence of the folders is not kept in the tibble. E.g., the data from folder 6 appears with the .id-column 18 instead of 6. Could you again help? Thank you so much.

Comment: Does using `all_sort <- gtools::mixedsort(all_folders)` solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Now it is in the right order. Your knowledge is really impressive.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again after two months, but due to work-related restraints I can only work on my project in my spare time now and then and you helped me so substantially. So I have yet another question: it relates to the issue in the initial question, but these specific files have column names with a hyphen, e.g. ab-cd. So I can not execute the otherwise working code. Could you help me again? Shall I post it as a new question? Thank you again!

Comment: Try adding `check.names = FALSE` in both the `read.csv`. `df1 <- read.csv(all_Files[1], check.names = FALSE)` and same for `df2`. @tsch

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I added check.names = FALSE in the read.csv commands. Unfortunately, the error message says that "Error in eval_tidy(xs[[j]], mask) : object 'ant' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... map -> .f -> <Anonymous> -> tibble_quos -> eval_tidy
Execution halted". The column name in the original csv-file is "Post-ant". There are also column names with "Inf-sup" and "Re-li".

Comment: In that case I am not sure what is happening there. Probably it is better to ask a new question with some sample data and expected output.